# how to debug asp classic code in MX dreamweaver

Tags: asp-classic, dreamweaver

can Any body tell me how to debug asp-classic code in Macromedia Dreamweaver, like we can debug code in visual studio because visual studio provide built in debugger. So is there any method by which we can debug asp-classic code in Macromedia Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to debug code in Dreamweaver MX.  Dreamweaver CS5 provides automatic syntax checking of code, though.

Answer (score 0):

I debug code in Dreamweaver by manually printing variables as html comments.