# How to debug classic asp page using Adobe Dreamweaver CS5?

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, iis-7

I am trying a troubleshoot the following error message on a classic asp page, connecting to a Microsoft Access database 2000 & 2002 databases. I am new to classic asp, and have a limited amount of experience. The coding is being edited from Adobe Dreamweaver CS5. The page runs without any issues for users which follows the firstname.lastname naming convention. The classic asp site is being run on Windows Server 2008 on IIS 7. However when the user has an apostrophe in their name e.g. Steven.O'Brien the following error is generated:

Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e14'

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'True'

Are there any steps anyone could please give to help debug a classic asp page?

Comment: You will probably want to use Visual Studio instead and attach to the W3SVC process and debug with that.    You probably are not escaping the single quote in the data and hence ending up with an invalid SQL statement (which also means you probably aren't using parameterized queries which means you are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to debug asp classic code in MX dreamweaver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582442/how-to-debug-asp-classic-code-in-mx-dreamweaver)

Comment: One way to debug this type of thing is to `Response.Write` your SQL string instead of actually executing it, followed immediately by `Response.End`. Then you will be able to preview your SQL in the browser and find any issues.

Comment: *"However when the user has an apostrophe in their name e.g. Steven.O'Brien the following error is generated ..."* - I'd wager that Steven is a relative of Little Bobby Tables.

Comment: Time to [learn about parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp-classic%5D+parameters).

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your suggestions.